# Accessing variable defined inside block

Tags: ruby, variables, block

I have this snippet:

```
class MyClass
    def self.callWithBlock (&block)
        print block.blockVar
    end
end

MyClass::callWithBlock do
    blockVar = 'Hello'
end
```

which gives me an error:

```
in `callWithBlock': undefined method `blockVar' for #<Proc:0x000000017ed168@./block-test.rb:9> (NoMethodError)
    from ./block-test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

How to access this `blockVar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `binding` at the end of the block, that would become the result of `call`-ing the block, and you can `eval` whatever local variables assigned in that block within the context of the binding.

```
class MyClass
  def self.callWithBlock (&block)
    print block.call.eval('blockVar')
  end
end

MyClass::callWithBlock do
  blockVar = 'Hello'
  binding
end
# => Hello
```